# Placement of the Hoshanot service

Tags: minhag, synagogue, sukkot, hoshanos

I’ve noticed that some congregations (generally *nusach ashkenaz*) recite Hoshanot after Musaf on Sukkot, whereas others (generally *edot mizrach*, *nusach sefard*, some Israeli *nusach ashkenaz*) recite them after Hallel.

What is behind this divergence in practice? What are the reasons to prefer one location to the other?

Comment: Were the Hoshanot in the Mikdash recited before or after the Korban Musaf?

Comment: If you put down the Lulav after Hallel is there any value to picking it up again later that day? The Mitzva is finished.

Comment: Can one take out a Torah without reading from it?

Answer (score -2):

After Hallel -- more convenient, only picking up / putting down lulav one time. (Also works well on weekdays, as people may have to leave early to run to work.) There may be more "pure" reasons, of which I'm not aware.

After Mussaf -- Rav Moshe Feinstein has a responsum where he notes that *the people of Jerusalem would walk around with their Four Species all day long*; we want to show that this is a mitzvah we'd like to do all day, so we put it near the end of davening.

Comment: On "weekdays" (in this context: aka biblical holidays) when people have to leave it's better to put it at the end so people can attend the obligatory musaf service